# WindowMaker change resolution

Tags: debian, resolution, virtualbox

I'm running debian sid in VirtualBox with the WindowMaker desktop. How can I change the resolution of my desktop? I don't have installed the guest additions yet. Running Ubuntu was a little bit easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, WindowMaker, it's been a while... Last time I used this WM, I was setting my resolution by editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Open the file and look for lines that look like:

```
Subsection "Display"
Depth 8
Modes "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
EndSubsection
```

Set the appropriate resolution and restart the X Server.

You can also try [wmakerconf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wmakerconf/):

> WMakerConf (short for Window Maker Configurator) is a configuration
>   utility for the Window Maker window manager. Unlike the WPrefs.app
>   program included with Window Maker, WMakerConf uses the GTK+ graphics
>   library.

Finally, WMaker user-specific configuration files are in $HIME/GNUstep, poke around in there, see if you can't find anything useful.

---